# grouping by area

Tags: channel-entries, categories, channel, grouping

I have a channel called 'news' and have a dropdown box of the areas they relate to. What I would like to do is search the channel and find how many have been tagged by that type.

I have my 'categories' in a custom field selectbox.

For example my list should look like this...

```
sport (5)
politics (6)
worldwide(2)
local (4)
```

it is essentially similar to a categories list in wordpress.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying Count of Large Amount of Entries - Best Practice?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/22081/displaying-count-of-large-amount-of-entries-best-practice)

Comment: Can you update your question to indicate where the sport, politics, etc. is coming from. Categories? Drop-down field in a channel? Relationships? Third-party taxonomy module?

Comment: done this, it is jsut a pre-populated selectbox