# Displaying Count of Large Amount of Entries - Best Practice?

Tags: count, query-module

we need a 'counter' which displays the total number of entries for a given channel limited by category and status.

Were originally doing this via the EE Stats module before the Status/Cats requirement was added, the Stats module can't handle those parameters so need another approach - we're talking about possibly 10k entries so we can;t sure 'count' - it's going to have to be a query or a plugin.

Does anyone have any suggestions for that sort of large amount? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The query module would do nicely here. Unless the information rapidly changes and 100% accuracy is necessary, I also recommend tag caching if the page itself is not cached.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM exp_channel_titles t
    WHERE t.channel_id = 1
    AND t.status IN ('open', 'featured')
    AND t.entry_id IN (SELECT entry_id FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id = 265)"
    cache="yes" refresh="43200"}
        There are {total} entries in Channel ID 1 with a Category ID of 265.
{/exp:query}
```

You can of course change the `channel_id` and `cat_id` as necessary.

Comment: Cheers, Derek. The info probably changes daily but only on a mass 'approval' of entries by Admins so I think the  caching is fine. 

Is there any way to add the status to this query to filter but this too?

Comment: Absolutely, I've updated the answer to include status filtering.

Comment: Headup... You may run into issues with cache clearing if you have too many items in the cache. Cache clears with several actions in EE unless you disable this auto clearing functionality here (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#clear-all-caches-when-new-entries-are-posted). Note... this says cache is cleared when you post an entry. This may have changed but previously it cleared when you posted or edited an entry and added or deleted categories.

Comment: True, Anna. Also worth mentioning that Memcached and Redis don't suffer from the disk i/o issues that high volume file-based caching can cause. If your host offers it, definitely [enable one of those drivers](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/caching.html#caching-drivers).

The above query isn't extremely intensive though and should be able to make full use of table indexes, so caching isn't critical, I just often reach for it when the data doesn't quickly go stale. MySQL itself will be able to cache that query too, for what it's worth.

Comment: Hi Derek - I have an issue with the Query you kindly provided above, don't want to open a new question on it so I'll outline here.

When I try to use it in a snippet or template I get the dreaded 'Disallowed Key Characters' error. I've tracked it down to the final SELECT between the brackets. If you remove everything between the brackets the error goes. 

Any ideas?

Comment: @segovius Disallowed Key Characters has to do with input - are you getting this error when you try to add it to a Snippet or Template? If so, it sounds like your browser or host is adding something to the request, as this data in your template wouldn't have anything to do with GET keys in the page request.

Comment: Hi Derek...yes, is the same error in a template or snippet. Is weird. What's the best way to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Check with your host, it sounds like there may be some server-side security software (mod_security for example) that is not happy with that data being POSTed, and is perhaps redirecting or changing the request to an invalid URL. What URL is in your address bar when you receive that error? Also, you can edit `/system/codeigniter/system/core/Input.php` around line 731 to: `exit('Disallowed Key Characters: '.htmlentities($str));` which will output the "naughty" input key.

Comment: I changed line 731 to show the error and it turns out it is the 'S' of SELECT. Very odd... leave the S out and it's fine!??

Comment: But then your query won't work, because `ELECT` means nothing in MySQL ;). I think that confirms that it is security filters installed on your server, you should check with your host.

Comment: @Derek, Thanks..I was just doing that to test it was the S. Got it working, was a security setting.

Now there's another problem:

`{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM exp_channel_titles t
WHERE t.channel_id = 2
AND t.status IN ('open')
AND t.entry_id IN (SELECT entry_id FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id = 110)"
cache="yes" refresh="43200"}
<h1>{total_entries}</h1>
{/exp:query}`

Which shows 500+ entries if I use {total_entries}. If I use {total_results} it just shows one. It should show zero really as there aren't any open entries and making an open one doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You should be using the `{total}` variable that the query is creating. `{total_results}` is the number of rows returned (always 1 with this query), and `{total_entries}` is a [global variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#total-entries) referring to your site's statistics.